# html to pdf font-face not working

Tags: html, css, pdf, fonts, nreco

i am using NReco.PdfGenerator to generate pdf from html. I would like to change the font-family of the pdf. I have a custom font and add it in html and it does not work.

```
<head>
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Helvetica LT W01 Condensed';
        src: local('Helvetica LT W01 Condensed'), url(../EmailTemplates/Helvetica-LT-W01-Condensed.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
</style>
```

But if I try to add another font from Google, it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" type="text/css">
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you probably also want to ask the NReco people this over on https://www.nrecosite.com/contact.aspx and then maybe you can even supply the answer yourself if they respond, to help future visitors that find this quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf` method that accepts HTML template as a string please ensure that all URLs in the HTML are absolute.

If this doesn't help, try to use ttf or woff font instead of woff2.

Comment: can you provide the url for woff fonts for nunito sans